# Visual programming in python

Tags: python, graphics

In raspberry pi using Python is there any way to make a program where according to the place you click on a designed screen actions can be taken and output given accordingly.
I am using the raspbian-jessie os and have a 7 inch touch screen, I want to create buttons on the screen. When I click on a button it should execute a program.

Answer (score 0):

you probably put the wrong tag, there is nothing to do with functional-programming or graphics, and still little relations with whether you are in raspberry pi or something else

you mean you are in linux and got a touch screen, and want to add some indicator on your touch? what desktop are your using, or something to do with the hardware.?

please state your question clear! and don't let me guess your expection

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) or [Qt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt). These are the most popular GUI interfaces for Python.